# Cannot unzip xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz; "No such file or directory" error

Tags: ubuntu, gzip

I have a problem unzipping an archive.

```
ubuntu:~% sudo gzip -dc xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz | tar xf - 

gzip: xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz: No such file or directory

tar: This does not look like a tar archive

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How to extract files from the archive?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command: tar xvzf xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz. If the error message still exists the file may be corrupted.

Comment: ubuntu:~> sudo tar xvzf xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz

tar (child): xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

tar: Child returned status 2

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
guess the file is gone...but how is that possible? i downloaded it directli to the folder witch i was trying to un zip-it. And now i can't even delete it. hehe :) What can i do? :) tnx!

Comment: did you remeber to download the file with binary mode? If not, that might be a reason for being corrupted.

Comment: hey me again. ja you're right. it was not downloaded with binary system. but now i downloaded with binary system and try to install it. and i get thet: ubuntu:~> sudo tar zxvf xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz
tar (child): xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: tnx 4 your hel mait :)

Comment: If you send me the link, I try to download it and extract.

Comment: Sry for late answer i was ill. here u have a download link. http://sourceforge.net/projects/xymon/files/latest/download

Comment: For me it works. I downloaded the file with firefox browser to my Win PC. SCPed the file to my linux workstation. And then did a:  tar xvzf xymon-4.3.18.tar.gz. Without any problem all files get extracted